# Button clicking but not clicking

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this weird situation going on :

1) In popup type form I enter some values 
2) Click Apply changes button

In all cases the  apply changes is clicked. However it seems like for this application when I click the apply changes button two things are happening :

1) The Click Apply Button is clicked 
2) The Pop Up from is closed which is a indication that the form got saved

However,  9 out of 10 times the pop up form is not closed i.e. the element is clicked only but no event to close the pop up triggered . I have also used java script executor with the same exact result

Comment: i saw such kind of issue when two buttons have the same locator. please verify the locator is finding only 1 element.

Comment: There could also be timing issues with the popup animation or something similar.
An easy way to make it more resilient is to add a visible check.

1) Check if the button is visible
2) Click the button
3) Wait for it to not be visible
4) If still visible, click again
5) Loop until timeout

Comment: Thanks Michiel. The issue is not with the click. The button is clicked all the time. This is  the use case : 

1) Click the button 
2) Once the Button is clicked the pop up form is closed which in turn saves the value 

But in most cases the Button is clicked but nothing happens i.e.  the pop up form does not close. The strange thing is If I use my mouse to click after that failed test same thing happens. I clicked it about 20 times and nothing happened.

Comment: Thanks Infern, in my case that is not the issue as every time the button is clicked